# Accordion not working after ajax data update : M2

Tags: magento2, accordion, data-bind

At page load accordion is working good, but when i replace whole  **id="accordion"** div using ajex after that accordion isn't working.

In ajax content have same html structure as below.

```
<div id="accordion" data-mage-init='{
"accordion":{
"active": [0],
"collapsible": true,
"collapsibleHeader": true,
"openedState": "active",
"multipleCollapsible": false
}}'>
<?php foreach ($categoryData as $category) : ?>
<div data-role="collapsible">
<h4><?= $category['name'] ?></h4>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
        <div class="category-image">
            <div class="fields-items">
                <div class="field">
                    <label><?= __("Image"); ?></label>
                    <img src="<?= $category['image_url']; ?>" alt="<?= $category['name'] ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can any ine help me , how can i re-bind , refresh accordion for updated  **id="accordion"**

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: i used jquery accordion.